# Accept payments during devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

How can I accept stripe payments during user sign up?

'Here is my subscription controller'

I have seen other people try to do this but didnt find a solution. Please help. The only time in can create a subscription is after a user signs up. Is it because i have

before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:new]

```
 class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:new]
  before_action :redirect_to_signup, only: [:new]

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

   def create
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
                 Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
               else
                 Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email, :source => token)
               end

     subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
      plan: "plan_DwAtwGCQIFXqEm"
    )


     options = {
      stripe_id: customer.id,
      stripe_subscription_id: subscription.id,
      subscribed: true
    }


    current_user.update(options)

    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription was setup successfully!"
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id).delete
    current_user.update(stripe_subscription_id: nil)

    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription has been canceled."
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_signup
      if !user_signed_in?
        session["user_return_to"] = new_subscription_path
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: This error simply means that your customer has no card saved. This is either because `token` is empty (so print it out to debug the flow) or because you are retrieving an existing customer with no card (first part of your if) and never adding the card to it via https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=ruby) shows quite little different. `Customer`, `Items {plan}` required!.

Try this one:

```
subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create(
  :customer => customer.id,
  :items => [
    {
      :plan => "plan_DwAtwGCQIFXqEm",
    },
  ]
)
```